# How to call function in classdef matlab

Tags: matlab, function, class, oop, object

I have a class and a function, I want to put function in class a just wanted to call the whole in another class, but it gives the certain error while calling, Is it a possibility to call function without calling it in Class constructor? I'm currently calling in class constructor but other possible way  is more likely. Five arguments are required in `func`, how can I make that function a class?

I have tried also in constructor while input argument is giving `obj.arg1=arg1;`
**My Code:**

```
classdef myClass
        properties 
            node;
        end
        properties (Access=private)

        end
        methods
        function obj = myClass()

        func(obj,obj,obj,obj,obj);
        end

        function  node = func(arg1,arg2,arg3,arg4,arg5)
          %some operation
        end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to have a separate `methods(Static)` section for those functions you want to call without instantiating an instance of your class. For any methods in the static section, you can do from another file:

```
<some code here>
answer = myClass.myStaticMethod(args);
<rest of code here>
```

Whereas for anything in the generic `methods` block without `(Static)` you would have to instantiate the class and then call methods against the instance, i.e.:

```
<some code here>
classInstance = myClass(constructor args)
answer = classInstance.myNonStaticMethod(args);
<rest of code here>
```